# Excel list, 2000 rows to 250 page templates

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

Unfortunately i am not a master of excel. I have 2000 rows of information that i must fill out manually. Then i use vlookup to sort them into sheets with a template that can be printed out. My problem is i cannot find a way to make the vlookup less manual. I am hoping i can be helped to find a way not to manually add 250 sheets and do the vlookup for each of the 2000 rows of information.

Is it possible to add a new sheet automatically or even tell the vlookup to look at the next row, like an index would with php/mysql?

Any help is appreciated.

This is a [working example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Ag6rm9FLYZ-EdFIzUHBXTlkwMHA0RExTdHdJZ29GVEE&usp=sharing) of what i am trying to achieve.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? A routine that takes your 2000 rows and places the data in new sheet with a maximum 10 entries per sheet?

Comment: Yes, or something similar. It must be printable too, so i thought maybe 10 on a page would make it easier for printing. Unless i format the whole sheet afterwards with print areas. Take 2000 rows and place the data into the sheets.

Answer (score 1):

There are a variety of ways of solving this. I got the following to work.

*Note: this assumes you start with one sheet in your s/sheet that has the main data list starting in `A1`*

See if this works for you...

```
Sub ParseData()
Dim Entries As Range, entry As Range, cnt As Integer, rowID As Integer, col As Integer, rw As Integer

Set Entries = Worksheets(1).Range("A2:A" & Worksheets(1).Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row)
cnt = 0
rowID = 0

For Each entry In Entries
    cnt = cnt + 1

    If cnt = 1 Or cnt Mod 10 = 1 Then
        Worksheets.Add After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
        rowID = 1
    End If

    With Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
        col = IIf(rowID <= 5, 1, 6)
        rw = IIf(rowID <= 5, rowID, rowID - 5)

        .Cells.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter

        .Cells((8 * rw - 7), col) = "Plan#"
        .Cells((8 * rw - 7), col + 1) = entry
        .Cells((8 * rw - 7), col + 2) = "Vol#"
        .Cells((8 * rw - 7), col + 3) = entry.Offset(0, 2)

            With .Range(.Cells((8 * rw - 7), col), .Cells((8 * rw - 7), col + 3))
                .Font.Bold = True
                .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous
            End With

        .Cells((8 * rw - 7) + 2, col) = "To:"
        .Cells((8 * rw - 7) + 2, col + 1) = entry.Offset(0, 3)

        .Cells((8 * rw - 7) + 4, col) = "Date:"
        .Cells((8 * rw - 7) + 4, col + 1) = entry.Offset(0, 4)
        .Cells((8 * rw - 7) + 4, col + 1).NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"

        rowID = rowID + 1
    End With
Next entry
End Sub
```

Comment: Wow that was amazing to watch, the outcome was a little different to what i wanted but it is very similar. I think the only issue i have with this is it isn't "dynamic" e.g. i update the sort of the list or change a value it doesn't update in the sheets. But for sure in the right direction. Highly appreciated.

Comment: If you want to update values in the list, you can change the code to embed a formula e.g. `.Cells((8 * rw - 7), col + 1).Forumla = "=VLOOKUP(x,y,z)"`